# show/hide elements based on title of clicked link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show and hide elements (DIVs) based on the `title` of the hyperlinks in jquery.

my html looks like this:

```
<a title="booz" href="" class="netro">booz</a>
<a title="books" href="" class="netro">books</a>
<a title="sam" href="" class="netro">sam</a>


<div data-title="booz" class="drag">something here</div>
<div data-title="booz" class="drag">something here</div>
<div data-title="booz" class="drag">something here</div>
<div data-title="booz" class="drag">something here</div>
<div data-title="booz" class="drag">something here</div>



 <div data-title="sam" class="drag">another thing here</div>
 <div data-title="sam" class="drag">another thing here</div>
 <div data-title="sam" class="drag">another thing here</div>

<div data-title="books" class="drag">oh well</div>
<div data-title="books" class="drag">oh well</div>
<div data-title="books" class="drag">oh well</div>
```

and this is the jquery code:

```
 $('.netro').click(function(event) {
  var title = $(this).attr('title');
  var allElems = $('"' + title + '"').not(this);

  allElems.show();
});
```

however, my code doesn't do anything at all.

could someone please advise on this issue?

I have to add that all the div's with the class `drag` have the CSS of `display:none;` to begin with.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/hunuxoloqi/1/ Try that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use class and attribute selectors

```
$('.netro').click(function (event) {
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    var $curr = $('.drag[data-title="' + title + '"]').toggle();
    $('.drag').not($curr).hide();
    event.preventDefault()
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/h5bg74fy/)

Answer (score 1):

There are three problems. The first is the selector is `"title"` when it should be `[data-title="title"]` The second is that you are using `show` when the elements are already shown, to fix this use `toggle` which does just that, toggles the visibility. And finally the links have an empty href which tries to navigate the page, instead use `href="#"`

So basically it should look like this:

```
$('.netro').click(function(event) {
  var title = $(this).attr('title');
  var allElems = $('[data-title="' + title + '"]');
  allElems.toggle();
});
```

See it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kxc0x5cf/)

Answer (score 0):

### Problems

The first thing is that the compiler has no idea what `"title"`refers to so you need to use an attribute selector. The next is that it has an `href` which means that the page will navigate.

### Solution

The navigation problem is an easy fix, add `e.preventDefault()`. To solve the hide/show, we use *attribute* selector, using `$('[data-title='+title+']')`

### Code

```
$('.netro').click(function (e) {  
    e.preventDefault(); /* Prevents page changing */
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    $('.drag').hide(); /* Hides other elements */
    $('[data-title='+title+']').show(); /* Shows the correct ones */
});
```

[**SAMPLE**](http://jsbin.com/hunuxoloqi/1/)